# Layout/Constraints landscape vs portrait container views

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I would like my display to look something like the following when switching from portrait to landscape. (The heights of the orange and yellow boxes equal the height of the blue in both portrait and landscape, the yellow box remains the same height, the widths of both sides are equal in landscape, and the margins remain the same in both portrait and landscape.)

Can I do this entirely using Constraints and Autoresizing?

Or will I have to do it programmatically?

Thank you

[image]

[image]

Comment: Put the orange and yellow in a vertical stack view. Put the blue and the orange/yellow stackview in a stackview. Vary that outer stackview between vertical and horizontal depending on the traits.

Comment: @Paulw11 Like you said. Just a quick note that he needs one constraint for the yellow view's height (either fixed or relative to the orange view's height), I guess.

Comment: Yes.  I guess it depends on what those views are and whether they have intrinsic content sizes or not